# Routing in angular by insert parameter in URL

Tags: angular, angular-router

Suppose I have a component A which routes on `localhost:4200/A`
I want to render A also when I pass parameters after A, like `localhost:4200/A/xyz` without any button click.

Simply if I hit the URL `localhost:4200/A/xyz` it should render component A here `xyz` is dynamic it may be changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a route definition with a parameter like this:

```
{
        path: 'A/:id', component: AComponent
    },
```

Then in `AComponent`

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css']
})
export class AComponent{
  data: string;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
     this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.data= params.get('id');

    });
  }
```